# Android : How to an Alarm Manager and Broadcast Receiver to perform a network task that will execute every day

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

In my android application I want to perform a network task every day at specific time.The task should happen only once on each day,If no internet connection is there on that time then the task should perform immediately after when a network connection comes.The service should work even if the application is not working and also when the device shutdown then the service should start after reboot.I want to give notification to the user when a new mandatory application version update comes,so in the network operation i have to check new version update which is mandatory for the application, and if an update found straight away give notification to the user and i have to give notification only once at each day. I know alarm manager and broadcast receiver are used for this, but how? Someone please show me some code examples.It is important that the service should work at every day once and if there is no network connection on the scheduled time then it should work when a network connection comes on that day.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement Sync Adapter will be the way to deal with this situation not Alarm Manager
The sync adapter component in your app encapsulates the code for the tasks that transfer data between the device and a server. Based on the scheduling and triggers you provide in your app, the sync adapter framework runs the code in the sync adapter component.

You can refer below official doc and example

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

[Example](http://www.skholingua.com/blog/using-syncadapter-in-android)

Comment: Does the sync adapter starts automatically after reboot??also does it run after detecting network connection when there is no connection on the scheduled time.

Comment: Yes...you can customize its attributes for specific interval or on network availbilty

Comment: How can i customize that based on network availability??

Comment: It handles automatically..You need to go through doc if you want to know in details https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html

Comment: Actually i have a sync adapter that will work on every 30 minutes and that will sync the data with the server.Now what i need is i want to give notification to the user when a new app update comes,so in the network operation i have to check for the new update for the app, and if n update found straight away give notification to the user and i have to give notification only once at each day.So is it a good idea to use sync adapter for this??

Comment: You mean app new version update or app data update ?

Comment: app new version update.Some times it will be a mandatory update and some time it will be normal update.I need to give notifiction based on the update type.

Comment: So in this case your better go for API approach....develop an API which gives latest version code from server and every time user open the app call the API and check the version code with install version and do necessary operations

Comment: You also need to implemented Push Notification to notify the user when new update is available.Push notification will be send from server whenever a new version of app is released

Comment: how server can send that push notification to all those devices where my app is running??Also how to build that kind of api that will check for update and notify user only once per day?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137628/discussion-between-burhanuddin-rashid-and-kjejava48).